# How to create a progress dialog in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to create a progress dialog in WP8, similar to ProgressDialog in Android [as given here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) or Progress HUD on IOS [as given here](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) ?

Answer (score 1):

In windows phone Progress Bar available to show Progress [Here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/15/31-days-of-mango-day-15-the-progress-bar/) is a link that describe more about Progress Bar.

If you want to use [This](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) type of  progress bar than You have to create your own custom progress bar with a loading image and angle animation.

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Set-image-loader-in-4ac4ecae) is a link that will help you to create custom loader control in windows phone.